# Sending chunked requests using Tsung

Tags: chunked-encoding, tsung

Does anybody know how to send POST requests with '**Transfer-Encoding**' set to '**chunked**' in Tsung? Do I just set the header in my request?

If so, will Tsung automatically chunk the requests? Is the chunk size configurable?

Also is there some method to disable the "Content-Length" header? My application expects only one of Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding, not both.

EDIT:

Sorry, I should have provided some sample code. Here is the Tsung snippet I used:

```
    <request subst="true">
      <http url="/blah/blah" method="POST" contents="{ "source_ip": "%%_requestip%%", "source_port": "%%_requestport%%", "method": "%%_method%%", "url":"%%_myurl%%", "http_version":"1.1","user_info":[{"username":"%%_myusername%%","client_id": "%%_myclientid%%"}],"headers":[{"host": "%%_apiid%%"},{"Authorization":"Bearer %%_mytoken%%"},{"x-api-key":"%%_myapikey%%"},%%_myheaderid%%]}">
             <http_header name="Head123" value="approxyhttpjkjdalsjdjasldjasldjlasjldjasdkjasljdlasjd"/>
             <http_header name="Transfer-Encoding" value="chunked"/>
             <http_header name="X-CorrelationID" value="Id-%%_requestid%%" />
             <http_header name="Content-Type" value="application/text"/>
      </http>
      </request>
```

As shown above, I am setting a 'Transfer-Encoding' header in my request.
I have two requirements.

1. How do I tell Tsung to send chunked packets? Is it by setting the 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' header?
2. How do I tell Tsung to NOT send a 'Content-Length' header in a POST request? My application cannot handle both Transfer-Encoding and Content-Length, it needs one or the other.

Comment: What did you try? Please post some command-line dump, or xml configs as [mcve]. Then we can help on the concrete case.

Comment: @hc_dev any further inputs?? It'll be most helpful if you can respond..thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can just override the header, see Doc's Changelog:

> 12.2.2. Changed
>
> [TSUN-307] - Allow all HTTP headers to be overridden by

Read the [Doc's, 6.2.2 HTTP](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/conf-sessions.html#http):

> New in 1.2.2: You can add any HTTP header now, as in:

```xml
    <request> <http url="/bla" method="POST" contents="bla=blu&amp;name=glop"> <www_authenticate userid="Aladdin" passwd="open sesame"/> <http_header name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache"/> <http_header name="Referer" value="http://www.w3.org/"/> </http> </request>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Overriding it will mean I'll need to assign some value to it right? What do I do if I don't want that header not to be sent at all?

Also, will Tsung send chunked requests if I just set the 'Transfer-Encoding' header to chunked?

Comment: I've read the docs thanks. It's just that it's not helpful and clear, hence the follow up questions. 

Thanks for your responses anyway.

Comment: Then please state that in the question (maybe with links). What happened when you set the header and POST a test request? This would be your [example] to work on :-)

Comment: I have shown the snippet in the original post. 
I have two requirements.

1. How do I tell Tsung to send chunked packets? Is it by setting the 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' header?
2. How do I tell Tsung to NOT send a 'Content-Length' header in a POST request? My application cannot handle both Transfer-Encoding and Content-Length, it needs one or the other.